# Webpack: How can we *conditionally* use a plugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack

In Webpack, I have the following plugins:

```
plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            drop_console: true,
        }),
    ]
```

I would like to apply the `UglifyJsPlugin` **only for a specific target**, so I tried using my intended conditional:

```
plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
        (TARGET === 'build') && new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            drop_console: true,
        }),
    ]
```

However, this fails, showing the following error message:

```
E:\myProject\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:164
            arguments[i].apply(this);
                         ^

TypeError: arguments[i].apply is not a function
```

Note that the above code is similar to having `false` at the end of the `plugins` array (which emits the same error):

```
plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
        false
    ]
```

So, the question is:
Is there a way to have conditional plugins on Webpack? (other than using variables?)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use this syntax which uses [the spread operator](http://2ality.com/2017/04/conditional-literal-entries.html)

```
plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css'
    }),
    ...(prod ? [] : [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()]),
],
```

Comment: With BundleAnalyzerPlugin specificly you can conditionally set `analyzerMode` to `disabled`, ie. `new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({ analyzerMode: process.env.BUNDLE_ANALYZE ? 'server' : 'disabled' })`

Answer (score 31):

I push onto the plugins array given a condition in my `webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        ...
    },
    output: {
        ...
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            ...
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    ]
};


if (TARGET === 'build') {
    module.exports.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            drop_console: true,
        }),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Without *variables* it will look like this:

```
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
        (TARGET === 'build') && new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            },
            drop_console: true,
        }),
    ].filter(function(plugin) { return plugin !== false; })
```

Comment: You can also do: `[].filter(Boolean)` (see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5699#issuecomment-330776517).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [noop-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/noop-webpack-plugin) (noop means no operation):

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const noop = require('noop-webpack-plugin');
// ...
plugins: [
    isProd ? new Plugin() : noop(),
]
```

Or better/recommended solution with no additional module:

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
// ...
plugins: [
    isProd ? new Plugin() : false,
].filter(Boolean)
// filter(Boolean) removes items from plugins array which evaluate to
// false (so you can use e.g. 0 instead of false: `new Plugin() : 0`)
```

Comment: Lol, webpack has a plugin for everything :)

Answer (score 2):

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    (TARGET === 'build') && new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        },
        drop_console: true,
    }),
].filter(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way is to set up multiple builds. If your `webpack.config.js` exports an array of config objects instead a single object, webpack will automatically do a build for each one. I have several different builds, so I define the shared the config as variables, loop over the factors that vary between builds, and within the loop use conditionals to check which build it is. For example:

```
let allConfigs = [];
let buildTypes = ['dev', 'optimized'];
buildTypes.forEach( (type) => {
  let buildConfig = {};
  // ... other config
  buildConfig.plugins = [];
  if (type === 'optimized') {
    // add Uglify to plugins array
  }
  // ...other config
  allConfigs.push(buildConfig);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have one webpack config, built upon another, and add a few plugins (and/or change output names, etc) in the latter one:

This **webpack.release.config.js** makes use of a **webpack.config** (development version), but uses more plugins...

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'release';

const config = require('./webpack.config'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

config.output.filename = 'app.min.js';
// use another plugin, compare to the basic version ←←←
config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    minimize: true
}));

module.exports = config;
```

Also [see here](https://github.com/dmachat/angular-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Creating-a-dev-and-production-config) for a full example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/) argument in webpack to pass `development`/`production` value to webpack config and then conditionally load plugins.

NPM Script:

```
"start": "webpack --watch --mode=development",
"build": "webpack --mode=production",
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  console.log("mode: ", argv.mode);

  const isDev = argv.mode === "development";

  const pluginsArr = [new CleanWebpackPlugin()];

  // load plugin only in development mode
  if (isDev) {
    pluginsArr.push(new ExtensionReloader({}));
  }
  return {
    entry: {},
    devtool: isDev ? "inline-source-map" : "", // generate source code only in development mode

    plugins: pluginsArr,
    output: {},
  };
};
```